# Ubuntu recognizes executable as shared library and won't run it by clicking

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, executable

I am first experiencing this issue on my fresh installation of lubuntu 17.04. I have used to use Ubuntu before and I hadn't this issue before.

I compiled my qt application and I can execute it through command line by issuing with "./". However, I can't execute it by clicking on file manager (neither PCManFM, Nautilus...) Both recognizes it as shared library file type.

How can I run it by clicking directly on the file?

this is what happens when I double-click the executable through file manager:
[image]

build-log:

```
11:20:05: Running steps for project APP_release...
11:20:05: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:20:05: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/bin/uic ../APP_release/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../APP_release -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../APP_release/main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../APP_release -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o mainwindow.o ../APP_release/mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../APP_release -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o foldercompressor.o ../APP_release/foldercompressor.cpp
g++ -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -dM -E -o moc_predefs.h /opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/data/dummy.cpp
/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --include ./moc_predefs.h -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/home/spectrum/trunk/APP_release/APP_release -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/include/c++/6 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6 -I/usr/include/c++/6/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include ../APP_release/mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../APP_release -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --include ./moc_predefs.h -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/home/spectrum/trunk/APP_release/APP_release -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/include/c++/6 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6 -I/usr/include/c++/6/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include ../APP_release/foldercompressor.h -o moc_foldercompressor.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../APP_release -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o moc_foldercompressor.o moc_foldercompressor.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib -o APP_release main.o mainwindow.o foldercompressor.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_foldercompressor.o   -L/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
11:20:10: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
11:20:10: Elapsed time: 00:05
```

Comment: How did you set up the project? How did you build it? How did you name the program? Where is it located?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is an ordinary C++ Qt GUI project built as release. It is located on my workspace directory on my home directory: ~/workspace.
What bugs me is the fact that it runs nicely through command line

Comment: As an ordinary *executable* project, or an ordinary *shared library* project? And what is its name? Can you show us the build-log?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude an ordinary executable project. Not a shared library. The lubuntu somehow recognizes it as shared Library. I'll add more information on the question

Comment: That all looks okay.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have fixed this behavior by adding the following line on my project's .pro file in QT:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -no-pie
```

The behavior is occurring because newer ubuntu distros set GCC default link flag -pie, which marks e_type as ET_DYN on the binary file. Consequently, the Operating System recognizes as Shared Library.

To work around it, it may be necessary to add -no-pie on compiler option.

Comment: Would it be more accurate to call this a linker option for people using IDE's?

Comment: It worked for Linux but when cross-compiling on Linux for Windows (https://askubuntu.com/questions/656219/building-a-windows-executable-in-qt-on-a-linux-system/656329#656329), I got this error using Qt 5: `i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-no-pie'`. To make the `.pro` file cross-platform, I had to add the line in a condition (https://forum.qt.io/topic/62028/detect-clang-or-gcc-compiler-in-pro/2):
`equals(QMAKE_CXX, g++) {
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -no-pie
}`

Answer (score 0):

What does "file APP_release" say on the command line. The "file" program should say what the system thinks the file is. Executables have "...LSB executable" and shared libraries "...LSB shared object". If it says it is an executable then it appears to be a bug in Ubuntu. If it says it is a shared object then your make log suggests it is a bug in the linker!

Comment: on the command line the APP_release runs fine! I can execute properly by running the executable from command line through ./App_release. The only problem is that any file manager won't run the executable because it is recognized as shared library

Comment: by debugging into ELF and I discovered that newer versions of Debian based distros are setting -pie gcc compile option, which causes this behavior