# How to make a qt5 app on Linux (Ubuntu) run when user double click?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elf, double-click, run-app

I'm building a Qt5 app on Linux (Ubuntu). Everything work well but when user wants to run myapp, they have to run it from terminal. I saw there are some apps can run when double click. Please give me some hints or keywords? Thank you very much!

Comment: Suggest : Create a "launcer" to run the application. I.e. an `app-name.desktop` file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329372/ubuntu-recognizes-executable-as-shared-library-and-wont-run-it-by-clicking). 
Add this flag to .pro: `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -no-pie`