# Ubuntu 18.04 mistakes executable for a shared library

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, makefile

I compile a QT application using CMake and make and every time I double click the executable I get the error "there is no application installed for shared library ".My application runs if I try to run it from the console.
How I make the app execute by double-clicking ?

Comment: The problem seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329372/ubuntu-recognizes-executable-as-shared-library-and-wont-run-it-by-clicking. But I am not sure how to elegantly build QT application with `-no-pie`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the execution permission. Run `chmod +x <filename>` then try to run executable again.

Comment: According to the note in the question post - "My application runs if I try to run it from the console" - the application **already does have** execute permissions.

Comment: Not necessarily: the executable might have been run with root/administrative permissions.

Comment: Do you mean that application is owned by the root and has 'x' permission for the owner, but doesn't have 'x' permission for others? It is possible, but I don't expect CMake to create such executable. And the error message is "there is no application installed for **shared library**"...

Answer (score 0):

So I find the error  you need to compile with -no-pie flag in order to work just as an executable