# script fails to launch application with desktop shortcut on boot but works in shell

Tags: arm, debian, boot

I'm trying to start a C headless application when the Raspberry Pi boots and logs in to the Desktop, under the default user pi. The raspberry's a 3 B+ running Raspberry OS Buster.

This is the desktop script:

```
$ cat /etc/xdg/autostart/myScript.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Some Description
Exec=/opt/myDir/launchMyApp.sh
StartupNotify=true
```

Permissions seem ok:

```
$ ls -l /opt/myDir/launchMyApp.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi root 3373 Mar 13 16:29 /opt/myDir/launchMyApp.sh
$ ls -l /opt/ | grep myDir
rwxr-xr-x 4 pi   root 4096 Mar 13 16:29 myDir
$ ls -l /opt/myDir/myExec
-rwxrwxr-x 1 pi pi 71272 Mar 13 12:48 /opt/myDir/myExec
```

And this is (the simplidied version of) the bash script:

```
$ cat /opt/myDir/launchMyApp.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ulimit -c unlimited    
LOG_FILE=/tmp/mylog.log
cd /opt/myDir || { printf "[err] unable to cd to /opt/myDir\n" >> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1; exit 1; }
printf "[inf] log start: `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` at ${PWD} by `whoami`\n" > ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
(./myExec 1 2 &)
(/usr/bin/chromium-browser --start-fullscreen http://1.2.3.4/whatever &)
exit 0
```

The output is always the same:

```
$ cat /tmp/mylog.log
[inf] log start: 2023-03-13 16:38:50 at /opt/myDir by pi
```

and *chrome always sarts*. However, `myExec` will only start if i login as pi and start it from a shell. Otherwise it just won't start (the very first few lines of its `main()` log to a file and it won't even generate the file).

I've tried `nohup ./myExec`, `(./myExec)`, `$(./myExec)`, `./myExec &` and variations.

Then i tried a simple helloWorld: same location, same permissions, same compiler, same output directory for logs... and it works, generating a small file. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* f = fopen("/opt/myDir/log/hello.log", "w");
    char params[16] = "";
    if(NULL != f) {
      snprintf(params, sizeof(params), "1[%s] 2[%s]\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
      fwrite(params, 1, sizeof(params), f);
      fclose(f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So then i copied the little helloWorld snippet that writes to a file and added it to the very start of the `int main()` of my `myExec` and recompiled: no log file created.

So i assumed `myExec` is segfaulting somewhere, although i would've expected it to at least print some lines to the regular log file or at least run the little snippet (yes i'm using `-DDEBUG`). I created another executable to generate a core file:

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* f = fopen("/i/do/not/exist", "w");
    char params[16] = "";
    //if(NULL != f) {
      snprintf(params, sizeof(params), "1[%s] 2[%s]\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
      fwrite(params, 1, sizeof(params), f);
      fclose(f);
    //}
    return 0;
}
```

and it worked once i added the ulimit line, so then i went ahead and tried `myExec` again. No log file, no core, no nothing.

All `core`, `hello` and `myApp` are identified by `file` as

```
ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, ...
```

which is weird as other executables are identified as

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1  ...
```

This is a compilation line from `myExec` (the host is an x86_64 Ubuntu Xenial):

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -std=c++11 -Wabi-tag -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DFLAG1 
-DFLAG2 -fexceptions --sysroot=/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld  -Wno-deprecated  -Wno-format-truncation \
-Wno-unused-result  -O0 -g -DDEBUG -I/opt/dependencies/dependency01/dist/linux/armhf/include \
-I/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld/opt/vc/include \
-I/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf 
-I/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld/usr/include \
-I/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld/usr/local/include \
-c File.cpp -o obj/linux/armhf/debug/File.o
```

where `--sysroot` points to a loopmounted Buster image. And the linking line:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld/opt/vc/lib \
-L/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
-L/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8 \
-L/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld/lib -L/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld/usr/lib \
-L/opt/dependencies/dependency01/dist/linux/armhf/dbg/lib \
-o dist/linux/armhf/dbg/myExec \
obj/linux/armhf/dbg/file1.o obj/linux/armhf/dbg/file2.o ... \
--sysroot=/opt/rpi/sysroot/bld -lextdep1 -lextdep2 -ldependency01
```

Considering the script that starts `myExec` (which also runs on X86_64 Linux and Windows) is the same that starts `chrome` and that if i run it at the cli it works as expected... i'm at a loss and probably overcomplicating something obvious.

---

**Edit 1**

Rolling back to a previous release, it runs as an executable just fine if cross-compiled in a Xenial x86_64 (has gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)).

When using Fossa x86_64 (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)) on the same commit, i must add `-L$(CHROOT)/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8` for it to compile (or it'll complain about not finding `pow`) and must add `-no-pie` (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332687/1831722)) for it to link as an executable, but it won't run anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I still need extra steps to cross-compile on Fossa, but i figured out the issue.

I have this in user pi's `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/opt/mylibs
```

My application depends on an external library which i've recently upgraded and thus replaced the file in this directory.

However, on boot the script won't look at `/opt/mylibs` (probably because it's not an interactive shell or somesuch) and instead tries to find the library in the system -- and it does find the old version to which my application is no longer linked against. And fails.

Upgrading the library's version that's installed on system (instead of just placing it in `/opt/mylibs`) fixed this issue.

(The original boot method relies on a python script and i was using a bash script to debug but neglected to capture the output of my application, maybe it would've logged that it couldn't find the lib.)